# How do I specify the Java virtual machine for Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse

Millions of programmers have been able to do this; is there something so obvious as the nose on my face, which I'm missing here?

I've been using TextPad with Java for a dozen years. Everytime Windows changes versions, I have to reinstall them. Somehow, TextPad finds Java and I'm all set.

I don't know about PATH or environment variables (maybe this is the thing everyone else knows and I don't).

Anyway, I downloaded eclipse 1.7 and copied the files from the ZIP into C:\eclipse on my Windows 7 (64-bit version) machine. There are NO INSTALLATION INSTRUCTIONS in the download or at eclipse.org!

What am I supposed to put on a command line (for a batch file) on in the eclipse.ini file to allow Eclipse to find the Java virtual machine?

- The location of javaw.exe
- The path of jvm.ell

... or what?

=> Tell me how, and I'll make a web page dedicated to this!!!

Comment: You downloaded Eclipse 1.7 or Java 1.7?

Answer (score 3):

How about http://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_run_Eclipse%3F ?

Answer (score 3):

Normally with a properly installed JRE, Eclipse will just run because the javaw.exe and java.exe proxies are added to your windows folder which is always in the path. But alternatively you can make eclipse use any other JRE/JDK by editing the eclipse.ini file and adding the following lines at the top of the file:

```
-vm
<path to jdk or jre>
```

Answer (score 1):

Windows > Preferences > Java > Installed JREs lets you configure any number of JREs.

The online doc (accessible from Help > Help contents or [on the web](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/topic/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.user/reference/preferences/java/debug/ref-installed_jres.htm?resultof=%22installed%22%20%22instal%22%20%22JRE%22%20%22jre%22%20)) explains this and all other settings.

Hope that helps.

Comment: i think he's having trouble launching eclipse, not configuring java within eclipse.